# Looping through a text file using StreamReader causes a "Cannot access a disposed object."

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following basic code to read a text file from a StreamReader:

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(FileData)
  Dim line As String = String.Empty
  Do
    'Error occurs on the next line after looping 
    'past the *last* line in the file...sometimes
    line = sr.ReadLine()
    'Some code here to parse and process the line
  Loop Until (line Is Nothing) OrElse (line = String.Empty)
End Using
```

I tried changing the Do Loop to `Do While Not sr.EndOfStream` I tried checking `If sr.ReadLine IsNot Nothing` and a few other things but I keep getting the ***Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'SslStream'*** error *after* all 105 lines have *successfully* been read and processed. This code has been working for a couple of years, but there seems to be some issue with certain files (recently) that is causing this problem.

I opened the file and I didn't see anything out of the ordinary. No extra blank lines, funny characters or anything of the like. Just a normal file with 105 properly formatted lines. So even know there is something about this file causing the error, I need to obviosly handle this programatically.

What can I do to prevent the `sr.ReadLine()` line of code from throwing that exception that I have not yet tried?

**UPDATE** Upon reading the last line of the file, the 'EndOfStream' property on the StreamReader goes immdeatly to: **EndOfStream: {"Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'SslStream'."}** It never toggles to 'True'. This makes checking for this condition problematic.

I think I have figured out why this issue only occurs sometimes: if I add in a blank line to the file at the end, none of this ever occurs. It is only when the last line of the file contains data. Still, I should be able to handle this programatically. Telling the vendor supplying the file to always add a blank line at the end should not be the solution.

Comment: You don't have anything in your loop that would end the loop.  Your `While Not sr.EndOfStream` should definitely be present!  Other than that, there's nothing in the code you've posted that would cause the issue you describe - so what other code is missed from your sample?

Comment: Yep sorry - trying to simplify the code and missed some of it!

Comment: Could there be a space-character of linefeed on the "empty line"?
Also, the exception mentions sslStream. Which type of object is this?
Because we don't see this code.
Are you somewhere closing the stream before you are done with reading?

Comment: "SslStream" doesn't sound much like a file.

Comment: It is indeed a text file that is loaded into a Stream object via a FtpWebRequest being downloaded from a secure FTP server.

Comment: I have no call to close the StreamReader inside the loop; only the Using statment can close the object which is outside the loop. Check my **updated** section. During debug I can see the EndOfStream property automatically toggle to that exception value upon the last iteration of that loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally - I got this one figured out. Some of the comments from my OP started make me look at this from a different angle. The *underlying* stream was automatically being closed. I started shifiting focus to the **Stream** object being *loaded* into the StreamReader rather than the StreamReader itself.

Turns out the *Stream* was the culprit. The stream object has a .CanRead property which is 'True' until reading the last line of the file when it turns to 'False'. This was causing the StreamReader.EndOfStream value to be an exception when there were no blank lines in the file.

Checking the value of .CanRead on the underlying Stream which was loaded into the StreamReader and making sure it is not False was the solution. The new loop is below and I made sure to use the short-circuit 'OrElse' or the latter condition would thrown an exception as before.

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(FileData)   
  Dim line As String = String.Empty   
  Do         
    line = sr.ReadLine()     
    'Some code here to parse and process the line   
  Loop Until (Not FileData.CanRead) OrElse (sr.EndOfStream) 
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : Based on the new information, I think the following is your solution.
You have to declare a string-object outside of your Do While-loop.
During initialisation, fill it for a first time with sr.ReadLine.
The rest should be self-explanatory, I guess

```
Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
    ' Display to console.
    Console.WriteLine(line)
    ' Read in the next line.
    line = sr.ReadLine
Loop
```

Comment: That does not work either, it gives the same error for the file I am reading.

Comment: Look at the Edited answer. By using the while-clause at the Do While-part, you won't have the fault of running through your code with the last line, which is nothing.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work either. Check my updated section. During debug I can see the EndOfStream property automatically toggle to that exception value upon the last iteration of that loop. That will prevent any type of call to 'ReadLine' regardless of where it is in the loop or how the loop is structured. The fact that the underlying stream is closed for me without me doing it is the root problem. It's like it is trying to be smart after reading the last line and closes the stream for me.

Comment: Do you also use EndOfStream in conjunction with my answer? But the do while I provided should be sufficient.
What type of Stream do you use?
Do you close it somewhere while parsing your content?